# Brute Force UAC windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

При запуске приложения от имени администратора, всплывает окно для ввода пароля, там нужно перебрать некоторое количество паролей только из цифр.
Как из скрипта python вставлять пароли в UAC?

Comment: Если целевой задачей является  взлом пароля, рекомендую подойти с другой стороны. Попробуйте подобрать пароль на сетевое подключение к сетевым ресурсам самого компьютера с использованием подставляемых учетных данных. Правда там есть таймаут на время ответа, но зато при попытках подключения всегда можно считать код ошибки и узнать было оно успешным или нет. И да, данный процесс автоматизируется.

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно - цель UAC точно такой, чтобы *предотвратить подобных попыток.*

Пароль возможно задать только *вручную* (с применением клавиатуры).